# audio player not working

Tags: javascript

I have created a playlist using jPlayer and jQuery cookie plugin and also set a cookie session to save currentTime of playing audio. After browser reload i want to start the audio from last saved currentTime.

Comment: Any error in the console????

Comment: No sir....... @Arjun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`time played` is retrieved from the cookie as a string, you have to parse it to be an integer with `parseInt()`. Replace:

```
var playnow = $.cookie("timeplay");
```

by

```
var playnow = parseInt($.cookie("timeplay"));
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7ec7xs9y/)